# delta writestream .option("mergeSchema", "true") issue

Tags: merge, schema, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I have a delta table of 3 columns with data. Now, I have an incoming data with 4 columns so the DF.**writeStream** has to update the data location atleast with 4 columns automatically, so we can recreate the table on the top of the data location. hence the old records will have nulls in the newly added columns, and the recent data will have 4 columns populated

```
eg:
id  name   addr             id  name   addr   phone 
1   lok    UK      ---->     1  lok    UK     null
                             2  ram    US     +1234
```

but while I use the following command as per databricks wesite, it shows,

```
 df.writeStream
      .option("mergeSchema", "true")
      .format("delta")
      .outputMode("append")
      .option("path","/data/")
      .option("checkpointLocation","/checkpoint/")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()

ERROR: A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table
To enable schema migration, please set:
'.option("mergeSchema", "true")'.
```

But I am already using mergeSchema in options. Please advice..
NOTE: .saveAsTable or .table functions are also not allowed in writeStream

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to change the checkpoint location.

For details, see the document [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovery-semantics-after-changes-in-a-streaming-query) .

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using foreach batch and then write the batch as delta format. This works for me.