# delta mergeSchema doesn't work using MemoryStream with spark checkpoint

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake, spark-checkpoint

I am testing a DeltaWriter class using `MemoryStream` by spark for creating a stream (rather than readStream) and i want to write the result on s3  as delta file with option `"mergeSchema": true` as reported below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemoryStream
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import io.delta.implicits._

case class EnrichedPerson(id: Int, name: String, age: Int, address: String)
case class BasePerson(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)

val data1: List[BasePerson] = List(BasePerson(1, "mark ", 30), BasePerson(2, "paul", 25))
implicit val encoder1: Encoder[BasePerson] = Encoders.product[BasePerson]
val memStream1 = MemoryStream[BasePerson]
memStream1.addData(data1)
val stream1 = memStream1.toDS().toDF()
val streamQuery1 = stream1
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "my/checkpointpoint/location1")
  .delta("s3://bucket/raw/data/..-")
streamQuery1.processAllAvailable()

val data2: List[EnrichedPerson] = List(EnrichedPerson(11, "jhon", 31, "street 1"), EnrichedPerson(22, "luis", 32, "street 2"))
implicit val encoder2: Encoder[EnrichedPerson] = Encoders.product[EnrichedPerson]
val memStream2 = MemoryStream[EnrichedPerson]
val stream2 = memStream2.toDS().toDF()
memStream2.addData(data2)

val streamQuery2 = stream2
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "my/checkpointpoint/location1")
  .delta("s3://bucket/raw/data/..-")

streamQuery2.processAllAvailable()
```

The first time the codes works well (`streamQuery1`) with certain schema of input(e.g. *col(A)*, *col(B)*, , *col(C)*). If i try to change the schema by adding a new column (e.g. *col(A)*, *col(B)*, *col(C)*, ***col(D)***), the same code (`streamQuery2`) doesn't update the delta table with the new column C, even though i am using the delta as sink with **mergeSchema** enabled. I'm not got any error, however the `streamQuery2` doesn't write any data.

According the spark docs [Recovering from Failures with Checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovering-from-failures-with-checkpointing), i could change the schema between 2 execution, because my sink(delta) allow the schema changes

> Changes in projections with different output schema are conditionally allowed: sdf.selectExpr("a").writeStream to sdf.selectExpr("b").writeStream is allowed only if the output sink allows the schema change from "a" to "b".

The output produced to s3 by the first execution from the above query is:

```
deltaTable/
|
|__checkpoint/
|   |__commits/
|   |   |__0
|   |__offsets/
|   |   |__0
|   |__metadata
|
|__delta/
   |__....
```

Inspecting the content of the checkpoint folder, i found out that there is no file with metadata regarding the schema of my data. Indeed, the content are:

`cat deltaTable/checkpoint/metadata`

> {"id":"b48487ca-5374-4b93-8e26-503184f2ed57"}

`cat deltaTable/checkpoint/commits/0`

> v1
> {"nextBatchWatermarkMs":0}

`cat deltaTable/checkpoint/offsets/0`

> v1
> {"batchWatermarkMs":0,"batchTimestampMs":1649859656284,"conf":{"spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass":"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider","spark.sql.streaming.join.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.compression.codec":"lz4","spark.sql.streaming.flatMapGroupsWithState.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy":"min","spark.sql.streaming.aggregation.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200"}}
> 0

In order to solve this issue, as reported in these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844839/delta-writestream-optionmergeschema-true-issue) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469385/writestream-is-not-able-to-write-data-in-delta-table), is sufficient to delete the checkpoint however the impact of this solution is strong because after deleted the checkpoint, how can i start from the same offset?

Can anyone explain to me why deleting the checkpoint the previous query work, even though there are no metadata about the schema into the checkpoint folder and how can i use both checkpoint and mergeSchema option in order to realize the schema evolution test?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Schema of the table is recorded in the delta log, not in the checkpoint. You need to check JSON files under the `_delta_log` director of your table (for example `/user/hive/warehouse/table_name`).

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for your feedback. 
I have updated my issue with more details. My point is, if i execute the same code by adding a new column than the previous execution, the delta table not been updating. Deleting the checkpoint, it work however i'm not able to start by the previous offset. So, the issue seems to related to checkpoint

Comment: ok, the problem not with the data merging, problem with input data schema...

Comment: Actually, the end result is that the delta table of the output is not updated, even though, the option "mergeSchema" is enabled. So the problem is "data merging" however it start from checkpoint because deleting the checkpoint, it works but i cannot able to start from the same offset.